# Windows 7 student discount

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot-camp

Microsoft is offering windows 7 at a discounted value ([see the website here](http://win741.com)).  Is this a full version or an upgrade version??  I want to be able to install this version on bootcamp on Mac OS X.  Will this version work for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

It is a full version. I got mine using the student discount as well.

About Boot Camp and Windows 7, [this Gizmodo link](http://gizmodo.com/5387353/how-to-survive-boot-camp-and-run-win-7-on-a-mac) should help.

Comment: that gizmodo page you linked to seems to suggest that it is an upgrade copy.  So given that logic, wouldn't it not work with bootcamp??